# Как удалить всех пользователей в Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

Необходимо удалить все аккаунты, созданные в Firebase. Удалять их по одному нерационально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Вопрос:*** есть ли способ сделать это иначе? Если есть, то какой?

Comment: Можно было бы и погуглить сначала :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40128630/5602823

Comment: @RedHairOnMyHead спасибо, на вопрос вы ответили, но это всё же не решило мою проблему, оформите как ответ

Comment: Данное решение является не моим, так что оформлять как ответ я его не буду. Если бы это было исключительно мое решение, основанное на моем опыте, тогда да. Почему это не решило вашу проблему?

Comment: @RedHairOnMyHead к сожалению, я немного не так сформулировал вопрос и получил соответствующий ответ. Мне нужно решение на Java, а User management API для Java не поддерживается. http://i.imgur.com/yBjVHDv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашёл [RedHairOnMyHead](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195780/redhaironmyhead)

> [Ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40128630/5602823)